# How could magic theoretically alter flora/fauna?

Tags: magic, environment, fauna, flora

My world is close to an alternate earth except totally different. The planets name is Ethuna, and instead of magma and a molten core, it's made of a ball of energy connecting huge masses of rock. This energy is of course magic. The magic comes to the surface through vents. While the planet was developing, it was very unstable.

On this planet there are humans, as well as sub-human, and anthro-human hybrids. The anthro-humans are going to be far more savage and nomadic people, in which the other, more humanoid races believe to be completely void of intelligence, like that of an animal. The sub-human races are a vast majority over regular humans, since there many different kinds that don't really relate to one another. The way they came to be was due to magic instabilities. I assure you I'm not about to answer my own question.

One race for example, is the Desfodovy, or dogfolk. They are mostly humanoid, with only dog ears, tails, and fangs, as well as heightened senses. The anthro-human equivalent is the Sakruwok, who look like a very large wolf-man. The way these races came to be was human genetic coding being rewritten and fused with canine DNA, caused by a magic fluctuation so drastic it cased an eruption through the crust of Ethuna. Some began to grow ears and tails and stopped, becoming the desfodovy, while others didn't stop changing until they became monstrous hunters who had forgotten their previous life. The sakruwok were closer to the epicenter, while desfodovy were further away. This all happened so long again the desfodovy race has their own religion and culture, while the sakruwok still run around killing to survive.

Ethuna has stabilized and now magic no longer interferes with genetic make ups. Now, applying this logic, I want to better understand how this would effect animals, or plants. I'm not a huge expert on genetics and while this is cool to write about, I find a lot of the ideas I come up with by myself would ultimately die out due to their impracticality. Believe it or not, Darwin was onto something.

Magic makes any combination possible, but not every combination can survive. According to Darwin's law, it's survival of the fittest. I so far have not found a genetic survival rate simulator, and have a very basic idea of how evolution works.

However I have a very small and simple ecosystem that I know is capable of surviving. At the bottom of the food chain there's algae, and what eats this algae is a small crab like creature that has a shell that resembles a mushroom, for camouflage. This little mushroom crab love to pick flowers, it's nest is like a small subterranean garden. in order to move these flowers to it's nest in batches, it will pick them, and stick them to the top of its shell.

There's also a very large frog sort of animal that camouflages itself as a fallen tree, and when it opens its mouth it looks like a large flower bed to attract prey. Each of the flowers are covered in a sticky saliva, trapping pollinators, and out little mushroom crab who just wants the flowers. Once our tree frog decides it's trapped enough food, it closes its mouth and starts digesting. Since it doesn't move around much in adulthood except to breed once every few years, it has a lot of over growth and parasites that develop. In order to take advantage of this there is a small creature that lives in vines and makes its nests by braiding and knotting them. While its using the vines on the tree frog as a home, it keeps it clean by organizing the plant growth, and eating any pests try to make the tree frog their home and harming it. This is causing a co-dependency, the tree frog stays clean and pest free, while the vine braider stays safe and has a free home.

to summarize, my question is:

How would animals/pants adapt to their genetics being fused with each other, in a way they could survive and thrive in ecosystems?

(I'd like either examples of a simple food chain (plant-> plant eating animal -> animal eating animal -> animal with co-dependency on animal eating animal) or someone to direct me to a website or other way to gain information on genetics and unique ecosystems)

I AM ASKING FOR A WAY I CAN TEST GENETIC COMPATIBILITY TO APPLY TO FUTURE HYBRID COMBINATIONS. I DO NOT UNDERSTAND HOW THIS IS TOO BROAD. EITHER GIVE ME A WEBSITE TO LEARN MORE, OR SHOW ME THROUGH EXAMPLES. I AM **NOT** ASKING FOR YOU TO CREATE MY WORLD FOR ME. I AM ASKING FOR HELP WITH SOMETHING I DO NOT UNDERSTAND. IT IS FRUSTRATING TO BE TOLD ITS TOO BROAD WHEN I'M ASKING FOR SOMETHING VERY SPECIFIC. A SIMPLE TEST OR SET OF RULES TO SEE IF AN ANIMAL CAN SURVIVE. AS I HAVE SAID MANY TIMES BEFORE, I DO NOT UNDERSTAND GENETICS. I AM NOT ASKING YOU TO CREATE CREATURES FOR ME, I'M ASKING FOR RULES OR GUIDELINES THESE NEW CREATURES SHOULD FALL INTO TO SEE IF THEY SURVIVE

Comment: @ Game Master you need to do a better job at structuring the question at the moment most people won’t know what you’re asking (it’s too broad) the admins will cut this post down very quick. have a look around the site at similar questions to get an idea on how to ask. If you want to respond to someone use the @ then there name like I have done. also add the magic tag everyone here loves the magic tag Good luck… you will need it here ;)

Comment: @CreedArcon did my summary help direct it back to what I was asking?

Comment: Given the magic tag, this looks really "Primarily Opinion Based".

Comment: @RonJohn how? I feel like everyone just throws that around.

Comment: It's magic, so *there are no rules*.  Their genes evolve however you want them to evolve.

Comment: Go read [this Meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5991/magic-is-primarily-opinion-based-by-definition-so-what-does-a-pob-vtc-mean), especially Molot's answer.  To keep the question from being closed, you need to explain your magic system.  Otherwise, as @RonJohn states, there are no rules and therefore no way to evaluate which answer is best (aka, POB).

Comment: @RonJohn that does not help me understand how genetics allow an animal or plant to survive. I'm asking how mixing different genetics that wouldn't usually mix would effect the survival of a creature. An animal can't survive just BECAUSE MAGIC

Comment: If this question is ONLY about the genetic hybrids, then remove everything about magic (including the tag) and stick to just what you want to know.  This is one of the cases where the backstory is distracting from your question.  (Remember to change your title, too.)

Comment: @JBH the magic is to explain how the genes are mixed, not how they evolve. I originally didn't have the magic tag, it was suggested.

Comment: As I mentioned before, if the question is "Can these hybrids survive?" then as background say, "don't worry how they came to be..." and ask only about the hybrids.  Explaining how you got them there is tripping a common alarm on this site.  If you don't clearly describe your magic system, then we can only assume that your magic is "godlike" and therefore the only answer is "it happens because it's magic," which you indicate above is an unacceptable answer.

Comment: @CreedArcon updated, anything else i should fix?

Comment: @Game Master frankly I think you have an already well built world that does not stray far from what you would expect from an idea like this. It is both sound and believable, so even if you get no answers from here you should be fine. Just follow what you have been doing no one will call you out on this as not being realistic (at least not loyal fans). The effort is there and that’s all you need sometimes when world building. Just some questions is (I’m a sucker for world building) the magic is it being used in your world by anyone (mages wizards) if not why use magic the word magic?

Comment: @CreedArcon there are a lot of people using magic, there was even a war around magic in the earlier development of civilization. I'm not really working on how the magic works or how people adapted, I'm human, and I've gone through quite a bit of history lectures, humans and cultures come quite natural to me. I also used to love learning about how the earth worked and how it got its shape, that's why I wanted to add a twist with replacing the core. however, my one weakness is adaptations and evolution in flora and fauna. My imagination often kills practicality in that department

Comment: @Game Master what I have just read you seem fine with the evolution of flora and fauna in your world; anyway with magic involved it would get rid of the importance evolution the most important is now adaptations new forms of life just came to be over night but from what I see you seem to have nailed that with the crab and frog stuff.  Imaginations fine so long as you don't of over bored (ten headed rat, something like that) but as I stated I think your designs are both sound and believable. I think you are being "too critical" of yourself don't let it rule you (happens to me to) wish you luck

Comment: Welcome to the site, Game Master. Please note that the Worldbuilding community strongly prefers specific questions with a narrow focus. While you appear to have put considerable thought into your world, the question you're asking here is a "create my world for me" problem, which is something we don't do. If you have a specific ecological setup you would like critiqued, feel free to ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Look, I can appreciate your frustration--this site can be a bit daunting to learn your way around at first--but leaving a caps-locked rant at the end of your question helps no one. I'll be honest; I'm still having a hard time understanding what you're looking for, unless that last bit is IT, and even that is still a bit too broad for this site. Evolution is tricky and unpredictable in a lot of ways, and once you've added magic to the equation, it gets harder for us to help. I feel like "magic" is just your world's catalyst though, which means the [tag:magic] tag can safely be removed (1/?)

Comment: since all it did was create these guys. if normal rules of reality apply from there, then the tag doesn't need to exist. A lot of us handwave details to get to a basic premise and work from there. Regardless, we can't look at a handful of creatures in isolation and tell you whether they'll survive or not. We'd need to know the environment they live in, the niche they occupy, any predators or prey they have, and by that point, you'll probably have figured out what you're looking for. (2/?)

Comment: I think there's also a bit of confusion with the term "genetics" here. You seem to be wanting to mix species--which isn't really genetics--but you're the one who decides which traits manifest, and it seems you already have! So from there, you decide which traits are advantageous, which aren't, and which exist but aren't really either. Advantages allow the creature to compete against others and survive, while disadvantages obviously hinder survival in some form.  (3/?)

Comment: Traits that aren't really either can just come into existence, and as long as they continue not being a hindrance, they get to stay. Hopefully this helps some, and feel free to hit up the [Chat] if you're just looking for ideas. (4/4)

Comment: By reading your last edit, I understand the question you are asking in that edit. I think it could be reopened but it look like a different question than the one you have asked or am I misunderstanding? i would suggest that you change the title to better reflect the question and ideally to make the text shorter by focusing on the main elements of the question, leaving the more specific details aside or deleting them. Because right now, that question is really long.

Comment: @Pleiades Thank you for your feed back but at this point my partner in the development has handed this off to me do to their frustration in the fact that well, for a better version, no one here has the intelligence to completely understand what we're asking. We are asking how exactly genetics would work for many different creatures on our planet if they were to either have their genetics mixed with another species or how they would change in certain situations (like after volcanic eruptions, in deep caverns where there is no light, on isolated islands like the Galapagos islands, etc.).

Comment: We are asking for guidelines on what would work genetics wise. Obviously not all species can be put together or survive after certain situations, but what are some things to dictate that. Genetics isn't everyone's major so you can't expect us to understand completely but it is common sense to know that when you merge creatures together that the genetics from both mix to create a new set. With the new set of genes comes with certain traits from both creatures but they can't just have a big head and a tiny body and survive, there has to be guidelines on what can happen to ensure survival.

Comment: Well, okay you're on the right track as far as gene-mixing goes, but I mean it obviously doesn't cross species-lines (much), and when it does, the two species are usually pretty closely related and their offspring are infertile as a result. Anyway, I still think looking at evolutionary traits--even though these creatures didn't evolve in the context of your world--is going to yield the best results for what you're trying to do. Let the magic decide what traits to keep, and then you can ask us if it's viable or likely to survive in your world or the real world.

Comment: @Pleiades I'm just not going to use this website anymore

Comment: I'm sorry you feel this website isn't going to be helpful for you, but if I were to make a recommendation, the Worldbuilding subreddit is actually a fantastic place to find like-minded peers who are often more than willing to brainstorm with you. Either way, good luck with your worlds!

Answer (score 1):

**Change the "Event"**

from what I can tell that this "explosion" event that mergers all animals and plants together would be more on the random mutations side things, then stable side (which is bad very bad) instant death or extreme agony awaits any creature that comes in contact with this "magic event". Best case mass stillborn in the population and difficulty in living; that's if the mutations are organized enough to effect the same race in the same way (most likely it will NOT)

so why not make the "Event" not natural but unnatural (or supernatural) so those gods (or god like) you talked about, why not use them as some sort of organized forced evolution experiment that went wrong (or right). charge the name magic and call it the phenomenon or the essence; like a force that has a will on its own. it will make it sound more natural. to the animals on this planet they would not see it as magic but a way of life, give it a name that fits that. just some tips like that will make the story more believable... or just slap the its magic stamp on it your choice.

Comment: I'm not saying I want all of the combinations to be stable. Failure is of course how nature moves forward, if something fails, it doesn't move one, characteristics don't get passed down. Perhaps explosion isnt the right word. The way the magic works is how lava works here on earth, leaking out of "vents" in the crust. now of course a volcanic eruption can be deadly not everything dies. I'm asking about how i can figure out which combinations would be stable.

Comment: @Game Master Then you would need to give us some of your ideas (science can be guest) the devil is in the details, like fly trap plant mixed with a bear (a trap bear) if not it will be hard to help you. Maybe rework your question and just give us some creatures that you have it will made it easier to tell if it would work.

Comment: aye aye, I'll get it edited asap

Comment: @Game Master Master i need to point this out, don't take my word (or anyone's word) as gospel its your story and your way. you are the god of this world, build it in your image

Comment: indeed. However, I like having outside ideas, especially with things I'm not very good with. so if I'm doing something that makes it hard for some to give their ideas, I'm more than willing to fix it